# jQuery not taking affect inside second child of ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

It is maybe wired, but I had a coupple of times problem with `:nth-child()`, this time on jQuery, I just can't select the second `ul` inside it the `li` and finally reach the `<a href="">` attribute!

To make it clear and simple, at the code below, I wanna remove the `href` attribute just to the second `ul`, not to the first one!
[image]

Here is the simple head:

```
<stle>
   .cool {
       color: red;
   }
</style>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $("ul:nth-child(2)>li>a").removeAttr("href");
   });
</style>
```

The html code (Should not change anything here):

```
<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<ul class="cool">
    <li class="aalsdlasd"><a href="http://www.google.com">Lol this row</a></li>
    <li>Lol this row 2</li>
        <ul  class="cool" style="color: gold;">
            <li>Lol this row</li>
                <ul  class="cool" style="color: grey;">
                    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Lol this row Gold</a></li>
                     <li>Lol this row 2</li>
                     <li>Lol this row 3</li>
                </ul>
            <li>Lol this row 2</li>
            <li>Lol this row 3</li>
        </ul>
    <li>Lol this row 3</li>
</ul>
```

And here the row that should change on the right way:

`$("ul:nth-child(2)>li>a").removeAttr("href");`

Find here the link to this problem [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kuonboo4/1/).

Comment: Click the `<>` button and add the code here in a [mcve]

Comment: It works if you setup the JSFiddle correction - add jQUery and use "IN HEAD" instead of "ON LOAD" https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/wkx01ak5/

Comment: Sorry I don't understand you sir!?

Comment: The editor HERE at SO has a button `<>` to create a snippet. No need to use JSFiddle but if you do, use JSFiddle correctly

Comment: ouu sorry forgot that :S... but see the picture, there are 2 links, the first link should stay, and the second one should me removed!

Comment: your html is invalid. a `ul` can't be a child of a `ul`. Nested `ul`'s need to be wrapped in an `li`

Comment: there are a bunch of ways to solve it. is this acceptable or are you looking for something different? https://jsfiddle.net/kuonboo4/8/

Comment: @MichaelCoker you mean the second `ul` should be inside the `li` and not out of it?

Comment: @FlamurBeqiraj yeah, well just that a `ul` can't be a direct child of a `ul`. Only `li` can be a child of `ul`. You need to nest your nested `ul`'s in `li`'s

Comment: And you don't even need the direct child selector, you can just list the nested ul/li structure https://jsfiddle.net/kuonboo4/10/

Comment: Thanks got it, thanks to all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is your selector. The first `ul` in your document matches `:nth-child(2)` because it is the second element in its parent.

If you want to match the `ul` inside of an `li` (i.e., a nested `ul`) you can do this instead:

```
$('li ul a').removeAttr('href')
```

By the way, your jsFiddle won't work as-is because you haven't declared jQuery as a dependency so `$` is undefined.

Comment: @FlamurBeqiraj See edit. Your jsFiddle doesn't have jQuery.

Comment: @FlamurBeqiraj Great, be sure to accept an answer so other users know your question is resolved!

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to include jquery by adding the next line on `<head>`  or before `</body>`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

use

```
$("ul ul:nth-child(2) > li>a")
```

instead of

```
$("ul:nth-child(2) > li>a")
```

demo

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul ul:nth-child(2) > li>a").removeAttr("href");
});
```

```css
.cool {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<ul class="cool">
  <li class="aalsdlasd"><a href="http://www.google.com">Lol this row</a></li>
  <li>Lol this row 2</li>
  <ul class="cool" style="color: gold;">
    <li>Lol this row</li>
    <ul class="cool" style="color: grey;">
      <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Lol this row Gold</a></li>
      <li>Lol this row 2</li>
      <li>Lol this row 3</li>
    </ul>
    <li>Lol this row 2</li>
    <li>Lol this row 3</li>
  </ul>
  <li>Lol this row 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @FlamurBeqiraj check the demo